# Mouse over element on top of another element without triggering mouseout on the bottom element

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

I've got two elements, one absolutely positioned on top of the other. When your mouse rolls over the element on top it triggers mouseout (or mouseleave) on the original. The upper element is not a child of the lower one.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mattcoady/ZCWvJ/816/

Is there a way to make the mouseout/leave event of the bottom element (the big grey box) ignore the covering element (the red box) *while* leaving the top element clickable? (meaning I **can't** use pointer-events none on the covering element).

```
$('#my_div').bind("mouseover mouseenter mouseout mouseleave", function (e) {
    var el = $("#" + e.type);
    var n = + el.text();
    el.text(++n);
});

document.querySelector('.cover').addEventListener('click', function(){alert('clicked')});
```

Comment: What browser is this in? For me on Chrome when running your fiddle, if I move my mouse from the bottom right hand corner onto the red box (that is, I don't cross the grey boxes on my way to it), I can hover over any part of it with all 4 counters remaining 0, even the top left of the red box that covers a portion of the grey box. My intuition is that the answer for you may be to store the state of whether the red box is being hovered, and cancel out of hover events on the underlying boxes while that state is true.

Comment: Yea it's tough to explain. I've painted in a blue area here: http://i.imgur.com/IqyTt27.png I need mouseover or enter to fire when the mouse is here (as if the red box wasn't there at all).

Comment: oh right, so you DO want events to fire on the underlying elements when that blue section is hovered/clicked? ehhhh..... other than storing the page coords of the bounding rectangle for the underlying element when the page loads, then checking in a hover/click event for the overlaying element if the mouse is within those coords, I can't think of a cleaner solution. Sorry, no time to code that up to the standard of an answer, but hopefully it might point you in the right direction? Good luck, it's a tough problem.

Comment: And of course that solution doesn't provide for the bounding rectangle ever changing - if the underlying elements are dynamic at all you'll need to recalc the coords whenever they change.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Yea I had a bad feeling about this one from the start.